# Webpack images optimization with image-minimizer-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I try to optimize the size of a set of 300 images (png, and jpeg) with webpack.

Here is my webpack config :

```
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  output: {
    pathinfo: false,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
              name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizerOptions: {
        // Lossless optimization with custom option
        // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
        plugins: [
          ['gifsicle', {interlaced: true}],
          ['jpegtran', {progressive: true}],
          ['optipng', {optimizationLevel: 5}],
          [
            'svgo',
            {
              plugins: [
                {
                  removeViewBox: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],

  optimization: {
    removeAvailableModules: false,
    removeEmptyChunks: false,
    splitChunks: false,
  },
}
```

All images in "images" directory is processed by webpack and image-minimizer-webpack-plugin plugin correctly, BUT if I run the script for all images files my computer going crasy hot, and I must restart because he freez :(

Here is how I load all image in my entry point to webpack :

```
function requireAll(r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
}

requireAll(require.context('./images/ckeditor/', true));
```

What's wrong with my config ?

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the `new ImageMinimizerPlugin({})` inside the `optimization` entry of the module.exports. It should follow a structure similar to the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      ...
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          options: {
           ...
          }
        }
      }),
    ]
  }
}
```

I had a setup similar as the one you referenced in your question, and my compilation times and resource usage were quite absurd. Changing it to the pattern stated above made the compilation time at least 100% faster using `serve` and 20% using `build`. Hope this helps!

Check the samples of the image-minimizer-webpack-plugin instances [from the official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/).